# Dockerfile without CMD or Entrypoint

Tags: docker

I am a beginner in Docker. Based on my understanding, a dockerfile will usually end of with a CMD or ENTRYPOINT and the purpose is that a process will get executed when the container start. Example

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM node:12-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
```

Recently I came across some projects that uses docker-compose. The dockerfile does not have entrypoint or cmd. Instead the docker-compose file has definition for the command. Example:

https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/

My question is whether this type of dockerfile without cmd/entrypoint is only created for dockercompose? Is it also useable for deploying the docker image to kubernetes?

Comment: Both of your examples above, since the base image is node and python, actually it still has the entry point. You may look at it here for example https://github.co/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/12/alpine3.15/Dockerfile, https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/master/3.10/alpine3.15/Dockerfile Defining the new cmd or entrypoint is to replace the default entrypoint comes from the base image.

Comment: I have a pretty strong opinion that Dockerfiles missing their `CMD`, or Dockerfiles that don't `COPY` their application code in, are incomplete.  These setups will work if you provide the missing pieces via Compose or other run-time configuration but they're not the way a Docker image is designed to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...this type of dockerfile without cmd/entrypoint is only created for dockercompose?`

Nope.

`Is it also useable for deploying the docker image to kubernetes?`

Usable for K8s, example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command: ["ash","-c","sleep 1d"] # <-- set your command
```

You can also set at the command line with docker run like: `docker run --init -it --rm busybox ash -c "sleep 1d"`

Comment: ok i see. you can also set command in kubernetes. So if you are running the container without declaring any command, then it won't do anything right?

Comment: In this case the [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) will be invoke.